# Dplyr - Error: Can't join on 'Texto' x 'Texto' because of incompatible types (data.frame / data.frame)

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying join two different data.frames by rows but is not working. The datas has the same columns names and the numbers of columns is equal too. The two datas has filtered from anothers datas and the column $Text has dots and dollar symbol (I supposed that is because its link to another dataframe).

I'm using union() function from dplyr and I already try the rbind() and always return some error. So what I do whit this?

The glimpse() of the two columns that is giving me error you can see bellow:

> glimpse(prev_tts$Texto)
>   Observations: 19,668
>   Variables: 1
>   $ `TL$text`  "não, eu não chamei ele de \"bozo\", nem de fascista, nem fiz qualquer provocação, como fazem, de forma…
>   glimpse(prev_tts_2$Texto)
>   Observations: 8,317
>   Variables: 1
>   $ `prev_tts_2$text`

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data that we can work with, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: If you can do str(data1) and str(data2) and post the result here we can help check the types of columns,

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I forgot the str() code

str(prev_tts$Texto)
'data.frame':   19668 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ TL$text: chr  "não, eu não chamei ele de \"bozo\"...

str(prev_tts_2$Texto)
'data.frame':   8317 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ prev_tts_2$text:'data.frame':    8317 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ prev_tts_2$Texto$`prev_tts_2$text`: Factor w/ 7428 levels "_\"Vamos por partes, feito Jair Estripador...